# Get Jpeg properties from Image in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to get Jpeg properties from a image taken from the image library in the phone. In another XAML project I could use

```
var myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myImageStream);
foreach(var imageProperty in myImage.PropertyItems)
     //do things
```

How should I do in Windows Phone 8.1? I need property with Id 274 (Orientation) to be able to rotate the image to correct orientation

Comment: Have you seen [the sample for reading image metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709941.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First be sure to allow access to the Pictures Library in your application manifest.

Then this code should work:

```
// First get the list of all your pictures in the pictures library
var allMyPictures = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
// iterate trough your pictures
foreach (var file in allMyPictures)
{
    // Get all the properties
    var properties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
    // Get the orientation
    var orientation = properties.Orientation;
}
```

Be aware that pictures taken from the phone camera are not directly saved in the pictures library but in a subfolder ("Camera Roll" on my Nokia). If it's the case on yours you need to adapt like that:

```
// Get the Camera Roll subfolder
var cameraRollFolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Camera Roll");
// Get all the pictures from this specific directory
var allMyPicturesFromCameraRoll = await cameraRollFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

This code was tested on my Nokia 635 but should work on any Windows Phone 8